# Spark-Scala: How to compare dates in strings of varying length and return minimum value?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, datetime

I have dataset of the following type where the first element represents the `userid` and the second element onwards string represents a `value` for that `userid`:

```
1004,bb5469c5|2021-09-19 01:25:30,4f0d-bb6f-43cf552b9bc6|2021-09-25 05:12:32,1954f0f|2021-09-19 01:27:45,4395766ae|2021-09-19 01:29:13,
1018,36ba7a7|2021-09-19 01:33:00,
1020,23fe40-4796-ad3d-6d5499b|2021-09-19 01:38:59,77a90a1c97b|2021-09-19 01:34:53,
1022,3623fe40|2021-09-19 01:33:00,
1028,6c77d26c-6fb86|2021-09-19 01:50:50,f0ac93b3df|2021-09-19 01:51:11,
1032,ac55-4be82f28d|2021-09-19 01:54:20,82229689e9da|2021-09-23 01:19:47,
```

I have to parse the `value` part each of the strings and return the minimum date from them. The strings are of variable/dynamic lengths and there is no set limit to the length of the string.

I tried passing them in a function:

```
val strFun = (str: String) =>{
    if (str != null) {
      val str_split = str.replaceAll("""\|""",",").split(",")
      }
    }
    (str_split(0),str_split(1))
  };
```

But the constraint I'm stuck on is to determine the number of dates to be returned for comparison and to pick minimum date from them. How can this be done?

Comment: For two days you keep accepting and un-accepting my answer (4 times if I'm not mistaken). Maybe you could try to adopt the current ideas to the latest version of your question yourself? Please remember that SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: I understand the SO is not a free coding service. I have been trying to implement the solution in the code myself and am using the accepted and not accepted option as a bookmark for my approach. I also understand that this is not fair to you and am rectifying this.

Comment: I’d also like to state explicitly that this wasn’t intended to be a reflection on you or to offend you, I was at fault for using the option so freely for my own reference and apologise for the same.

Comment: Dont't worry! Everything is ok. I was just a surprised that you changed your mind that often :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First split the string. The result is an string array. Using `transform` from each element of the array the date string is extracted (using `regexp_extract`) and converted into a timestamp. Now we have an array of timestamps from which we take the minimal value.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("min_date", split('column, ","))
  .withColumn("min_date", array_min(transform('min_date,
      c => to_timestamp(regexp_extract(c, "\\|(.*)$", 1)))))
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+------+--------------------+-------------------+
|userid|              column|           min_date|
+------+--------------------+-------------------+
|  1004|value=bb5469c5|20...|2021-09-19 01:25:30|
| 1018.|value=36ba7a7|202...|2021-09-19 01:33:00|
|  1020|value=23fe40-4796...|2021-09-19 01:34:53|
| 1022.|value=3623fe40|20...|2021-09-19 01:33:00|
|  1028|value=6c77d26c-6f...|2021-09-19 01:50:50|
|  1032|value=ac55-4be82f...|2021-09-19 01:54:20|
+------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Version 3 vs version 2.4?

Comment: Yes, I also checked this out. It caused an issue for me because the Spark version running is 2.4

Comment: Nice score 9999

Comment: @PixieDev could you try to replace the second `withColumn` line with `.withColumn("min_date", array_min(expr("transform(min_date, c -> to_timestamp(regexp_extract(c, '\\\\|(.*)$', 1)))")))`? I think that should work for 2.4